# new composer-wallet - jszip error

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am making a new composer-wallet with composer 0.19.0

All test passed fine - test based on composer-wallet-filesystem

I can successfully import business network cards to the new wallet and use them for transactions.

I am only one issue

```
$ composer card list
Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html
Command failed
```

I tryed to update jszip to the lastest version in composer-cli, but same problem

Here is the environment variable to configure the connection

```
export NODE_CONFIG='{
  "composer": {
    "wallet": {
      "type": "composer-wallet-mongodb",
      "desc": "Uses a local mongodb instance",
      "options": {
        "uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/yourCollection",
        "collectionName": "myWallet",
        "options": {

        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Any help is welcomed

Comment: I have briefly tested with `composer-wallet-filesystem` and did not see that error.  Can you share your default.json or environment variable?

Comment: I updated the original post with the environment variable